# How is pax used by llpp pdf viewer?

Tags: pdf, pax

Yesterday I installed llpp.  In the [help file](https://github.com/moosotc/llpp/blob/master/help.ml) it states:

> double/triple/quadruple/quintuple clicks in view mode will pipe the word/line/block/page through pax command when Ctrl is held and selection command otherwise

It also specifies these key bindings:

> x                   - run pax command on selected region

and

> -M          - toggle pax mode

The pax man page description of the command is:

> pax will read, write, and list the members of an archive file and will copy directory hierarchies.  pax operation is independent of the specific archive format and supports a wide variety     of different archive formats.  A list of supported archive formats can be found under the description of the -x option.

I have not used pax before and familiarity with archive files is mostly through downloading them and installing the programs they contain.  I am no means a professional developer. It is just that it is frustrating not to understand the pax references in the llpp help file, especially how they are related to selected text and what pax is supposed to do in that context.

I can't even say that I have need of the pax functionality, but I would still be happy to understand it.  If I did, maybe I would find it useful!

If I do select text while pressing the Ctrl key or if I type "x" with text selected, nothing seems to happen, so I am definitely missing something.

The other thing I did was to explore some of the llpp files such as [main.ml](https://github.com/moosotc/llpp/blob/master/main.ml) in which "pax" occurs 28 times in different ways.  However, I don't know enough to be able to understand the implications of those occurrences  and how they are related to the references in the help file.

Any explanation or link to where an explanation can be found would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After opening an [issue](https://github.com/moosotc/llpp/issues/128) in the llpp repository in which I placed a link to this question, the repository owner answered it as follows:

> PAX is an acronym for "Point And X" so you point to the word/line/whatever and press 'x' :)

and

> ...pax in llpp has no connection to posix pax utilty.

Talk about "barking up the wrong tree"!